# Подключение web-камеры на сайте

Tags: jquery, камера, javascript, кроссбраузерность

Как подключить web камеру? Есть рабочий вариант для chrome через HTML 5.
Что делать с остальными браузерами?

Comment: Ну конечно относится, я же говорю не просто подключить, а на сайт прикрутить. Соответственно на стороне клиента нужен какой-то код для получения потока и управления(play, pause).

На клиенте естественно используем js+jquery. Cервер php? но он тут ни к чему.

Answer (score 2):

На хабре было: [Создание видео трансляции на JS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/172419/)

> Сегодня я расскажу, как можно организовать прямую трансляцию изображения с веб-камеры с помощью HTML5/JS и NodeJS, а так же PHP.

Comment: Это только в хроме работает

Comment: В ночном билде Firefox скорее всего тоже поддерживается, но так или иначе, кросс-браузерности в таком вопросе ждать рановато.